# How to make all my routes in camel go async?

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

So we have a camel app that for the moment was ok. It has many routes that form a huge tree. 
Then we received the requirement to go in parallel for certain messages. Problem is that although it is easy to parallelize one route (using `.threads()`  or `.parallelProcessing()` after a splitter) it may happen that two different threads will send msgs to the same route (that doesn't run in parallel) and thus block. 
Now I'd like to avoid going through all the application and modify all routes to be multithreaded (even because that could possibly break the behaviour of the app).

Any solution you can think of?

Comment: If the routes was not designed to run in parallel to start off with then just adding .threads or .parallelProcessing is going to be problematic. So right off the top of my head and with the little detail you have provided I don't think this is easy to do. Just a suggestion but you mentioned that there is a tree of routes all connected? If this is the case why not try using the SEDA component for each of these routes. SEDA allows you to run routes asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [SEDA](https://camel.apache.org/seda.html) in your routes. You can specify options `concurrentConsumers` to add another level of concurrency.

There are some limitations you have to be aware of. Most important, the `size` of a SEDA queue is unbounded. From the Camel docs:

> From Camel 2.3 onwards, the size is unbounded by default. Notice: Mind
>   if you use this option, then its the first endpoint being created with
>   the queue name, that determines the size. To make sure all endpoints
>   use same size, then configure the size option on all of them, or the
>   first endpoint being created. From Camel 2.11 onwards, a validation is
>   taken place to ensure if using mixed queue sizes for the same queue
>   name, Camel would detect this and fail creating the endpoint.

SEDA can speed up your processes a lot, but you have to watch your memory consumption and perhaps CPU load.

*edit* You might want to check out [Camel Disruptor](https://camel.apache.org/disruptor.html) too. Thanks to [@mdnghtblue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2066579/mdnghtblue) for the tip.

Comment: Check out disruptor for even faster message processing than SEDA. =)